# TYPO3 9+: Multiple user_uploads related to page tree

Tags: typo3, typoscript

is it possible to use different user_uploads by page tree in TYPO3 9+?

Informations:
Multiple companies are using the same TYPO3 instance for their websites.

Example #1:
An editor is placing images in a content element on a page of a page tree with drag'n'drop. Normally the files would be uploaded to the user_upload folder. If you have a huge amount of backend editors the user_upload folder will be a mass in a short time and nobody feels responsible for the files. I know that you can see if a file is used by its references in the info section but it would be much easier if a company would have its own user_upload directory (maybe subfolder of it).

Did anyone faced the same problem an has a solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should configure your user groups and their users in such a way that they use the correct storage. you can read about it here:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/master/en-us/UserTsconfig/Options.html#defaultuploadfolder

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/AccessControl/MoreAboutFileMounts/Index.html

Comment: Using user groups to define the default upload folder is a good solution if the editors are only able to edit their own company pages. Unfortunately some editors are able to edit multiple page trees